# Check if a string longer than xx characters without going through the entire string with strlen()?

Tags: php, string

I'm displaying some very very long text strings with a show more link. So I need a way to find out how long the string is.

I know I can simply use `strlen()` to size the string up and then compare the returned length against a limit like 50 characters but for very long strings I think it's a performance drag, especially considering there are nearly a thousand strings to be gauged per user request.

So is there any way to just make sure if the string is longer than 50 characters and then stop?

I know I can make an in-house function to go through the string character by character but is there any better practice in this case as I believe this is a rather common problem?

Comment: How about [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing you need to check if the string is longer then 50 characters, then you can try to check if the 50th character exists.

For example, for a string of 25 chars long I need to know if it's longer then 20 characters or not.

```
    $str = '123456789qwertyuiopasdfgh';
    if($str[20] != '') echo 'It is longer';
    else echo 'It is not';
```

I'm not sure if it's faster then simple strlen, but you can try some performance tests C:

UPD: Also, note that the index starts from 0

Comment: Beware, this will trigger a Notice when false.